# How can I send any error messages to a file when running Mysqldump?

Tags: bash, email, error-handling, cron, mysql

I'm pretty new to using MySql from the command line, so I really need some advice here.

Basically, I've written a bash script that backs up my databases on selected days via a cron job. It's working just fine, but I would like to know if there is any way I can direct any error messages from mysqldump emailed to me in the off chance that there's something wrong. Here's the key part of the code that's doing the dump:

```
mysqldump -u user -h localhost --all-databases | gzip -9 > $filename
```

Is there any way to set up a condition that would capture any error messages and send them in an email?

Blain

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
mysqldump -u user -h localhost --all-databases 2> error.log | gzip -9 > $filename
```

In particular, in bash you can redirect any output descriptor to something else by using the `n>` syntax, notice the LACK of space between n and > :)

Email the error.log to yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using cron to run the job.  Which is great, because cron already has a mail sending feature built in--no need for writing to a temporary file nor using support scripts.  Just do this:

```
MAILTO=yourname@example.com
00 14 * * * mysqldump ... | gzip -9 >filename # or invoke a script here
```

And like magic, any output from the job will be mailed to you.